# Excel Sequence a set of values

Tags: arrays, excel, sequence

Is it possible in excel to sequence a set of values?

I would like to create a sequence for a set of names

[image]

Like in the sequence formula, if I set the number of row to 3, it should spill my array A1:A10 3x as well like in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with a formula the referenced range and output ranges will need to be separate.

But using dynamic array formula we can spill the results.

```
=LET(rng,A1:A10,INDEX(rng,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)*B1,,0),ROWS(rng))+1))
```

[image]

Comment: Sir not posting as an answer since yours is elegant, but I tried an alternative way. `=LET(x,TOCOL(INDEX(A1:A10,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A10)))&"-"&SEQUENCE(,B1)),
y,TEXTBEFORE(x,"-"),z,TEXTAFTER(x,"-"),SORTBY(y,z))`